# Linux Subsystem: Change Directory by Using Windows File Path

Tags: linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

If I want to change the directory of my Linux Subsystem to a directory that I opened in Windows Explorer, then I have to replace the `\`, remove the `:` and prepend `/mnt/`.

I found out that the command `wslpath -a 'C:\Windows'` does this, but then I still have to copy-paste the result to change the dir. So I tried `wslpath -a 'C:\Windows' | cd` but that didn't work.

Edit: Would be great to have this working as an alias like e.g. `cdwin C:\Windows`

Comment: just use `cd /mnt/c/windows` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible to do.  You can use a shell function (e.g., in your `~/.bashrc`) that invokes `wslpath` and `cd`:

```
cdwin () {
    cd "$(wslpath -a "$1")"
}
```

However, having said that, you'll have to place quotation marks around your Windows path.  The shell interprets backslashes specially (as escape characters) and if you omit the quotation marks the backslashes will probably be stripped out.  There isn't a way to avoid this, since it's how all Unix shells work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment, I don't have much reputation

asdsad [@bkk2204 answer's](https://superuser.com/a/1540843) really a great idea.

But for your code, you're actually pretty close!

> So I tried `wslpath -a 'C:\Windows' | cd` but that didn't work

try this instead

```
cd `wslpath -a 'C:\Windows'`
```

you can even do eviromentment variables

```
cd `wslpath -u $(wslvar windir)`
```

or

```
cd $(wslpath -u `wslvar windir`)
```

or

```
cd $(wslpath -u $(wslvar windir))
```

However to do wslvar you need to install [wslu](https://wslutiliti.es/wslu/install.html) (pre-installed in ubuntu).

Windir is part of environment variables.

To print list of enviroment variables

```
powershell.exe "Get-ChildItem Env:"
```